# onAuthenticate for normal buttons in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I am was using a login control, but I wanted a slightly more customized look so I I used textfields for the username and password. And tried to use an ImageButton for the "Log in" button but it seems that login had a "onAuthenticate" property but ImageButton does not. Is there any way that I can have the functionality of "onAuthenticate" on my ImageButton?

ImageButton:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" ValidationGroup="Login"
    ImageUrl="~/Images/loginExtranet.png"/>
```

this is important because I need to call the following functon:

```
protected void LoginExtranet_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
// Check Database for username and password
// ....
// if correct set e.Authenticated = true
// redirect to destination
}
```

ImageButton control doesn't have a property to call this function, The Login control does.

Comment: And how exactly are you authenticating the user?

Comment: Ok what I think you are saying is that you were using the Login control, but you have moved away from that to your own custom one? Did you try just styling the controls via CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the button click event and use the FormsAuthenitcation.SetAuthCookie method to login the user after you make the checks

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I authenticate credentials using a `CustomValidator` and then in an `OnClick` event I can catch the `if(Page.IsValid)` property and then use the `FormsAuthentication` class functionality as needed.